# Else If condition given precedence over while condition?

Tags: c

Please excuse this beginner's question. I've just started programming and I'm using C for the code below.

The purpose of this code is for the computer to guess a number the user has picked. The computer will narrow down the numbers available based on queues like 'too low' or 'too high'.

```
computer_guess(int answer)
{
    int lownum, highnum, guess, answer;

    //Instructions
    printf("Please use 'h' for too high or 'l' for too low ");
    printf("for incorrect guess. Use 'c' if the guess is right.\n");

    guess = (lownum + highnum)/2;
    printf("\n %d. \n", guess);
    printf("Is this the right number?");

    do
    {
        answer = getchar();

        if (answer == 'h') 
        {
            guess = (lownum + (highnum -1))/2;
            printf("%d \n", guess);
        }

        else if (answer == 'l') //If the computer's guess is too high.
        {
            guess = ((lownum + 1) + highnum)/2;
            printf("%d \n", guess);
        }

        else if (answer != '\n')//If the user enters letters other than 'h' or 'l', an error message will be returned.
        {
            fflush(stdin);  
            printf("Invalid. Please use either h (too high), l (too low) or c (correct).");
        }

    } while (answer != 'c');

    if (answer == 'c')//If the correct answer is given, the game will end.
    {
        printf("The computer has guessed the right number.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that my code seems to ignore my while condition (while (answer != 'c')). In my output, even if I enter 'c', it prints the Error statement in the last "else if" block and statement about being right.

This is the output:

```
 Invalid. Please use either h (too high), l (too low) or c (correct). The computer has guessed the correct answer!
```

What do I need to do to make sure the error isn't printed when 'c' is entered?

Thank you!

Comment: `if (answer == 'c')` is unneeded here, you just tested it with your `while`

Comment: Just test for `c` somewhere, you may extend the condition `if (answer!='\n' && answer!='c')`...

Comment: you need `else if (answer != '\n' && answer != 'c')`

Comment: `'c' != '\n'`. Why would you expect the "incorrect" message to not be printed when `answer` is `'c'`?

Comment: when the answer is 'c', the condition of the last if is true ('c' != '\n'), so it will execute that block on anything that is not \n, including 'c'.

Comment: @RSahu not this time it isn't

Comment: Do not `fflush(stdin);`, is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use some print statements or gdb to debug your code.

Comment: `guess = (lownum + highnum)/2;` is using *uninitialised* variables.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - thank you. your suggest did the trick!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - thank you to your suggestion as well!

Comment: Your `if-else if- else` chin tests the same integer variable for a specific literal value in every condition.  In this case a `switch` would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements of your program are executed in the order pre-defined by C standard. This includes the computation of the `while` condition of the `do`/`while` loop.

The loop checks the condition upon reaching the end of loop's body. This includes execution of all `if` statements inside the loop, along with their `else` branches. Since you have no special handling for `'c'` *inside* your loop, `if (answer != '\n')` branch gets executed, and gives the printout that you see.

You can fix this by using a "forever" loop, and handling `'c'` input inside its body:

```
for (;;) {
    answer = getchar();
    if (answer == 'c')  {
        break;
    }
    ... // The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense. I was under the assumption that while statement at the end would check for the condition. Clearly, that's not the case. I ended up keeping the do-while loop with J.F. Fabre and J.B. Yunes' suggestion of extending my last condition to include a test for answer == 'c'.

Comment: @lo123 it **does** check the condition but **after** your `else` executes.

Comment: C execution is linear, you can always determine what statement will execute next so long as you have sufficient knowledge of the program state. do-while is not some magical construct that checks the condition on a continuous basis, instead it is only checked at the end of the loop body (just as the test condition of a for or regular while is executed prior to each entry to the loop body). Making it a real "execute this code only so long as the condition holds" would be enormously complicated.